# Android Market says app requires update immediately after installation

Tags: android, air

I put my first Android app in the Market. Users are complaining that, immediately after they install the app, the Market says it needs to be updated. They are on the right version. I see the same thing. Any suggestions?

BTW, this is an AIR for Android application.